# No App Store updates after changes in terms and conditions

Tags: apple-id, mac-appstore

In the last week the MacOS App Store has refused to update some free apps (Microsoft Remote Desktop, TickTick). I get a notification that the App Store's T&Cs have changed and I must agree with them to proceed. But when I do this, I get another message telling me that it isn't possible to reload the article because it was bought or refunded for another user. This is for free apps, so I've no idea what the message is trying to tell me.

Having, a few years ago, had all kinds of "fun" with various Apple IDs (probably the most broken SSO out there), I settled on one and have stuck with it. I suspect the best approach will be to delete and reinstall. Fortunately, I don't have a lot of associated data to lose. But, before I do this, I wonder if anyone else has come across this?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: MacOS 10.15.7 – won't update beyond this until they fix all the bugs.

Comment: Any app that's ever been on the Mac is owned by the ID that first purchased it [even if it was free]. Part of your ongoing issue if you've been using multiple IDs is going to be to figure out which ID 'purchased' which app & sign in with the correct credentials each time.

Comment: One workaround might be to invite them all to Family Sharing, so at least most apps can then have multiple 'family' owners. [I haven't tested this].

Comment: Both these apps were installed/purchased with the current user.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to delete the apps in Finder and reinstall them. Fortunately, all config, login data, etc. was preserved so this was fairly painless. Given the list of *similar* questions I suspect this is yet another bug somewhere in the App Store.